# Accessing to a contract's public array from javascript

Tags: solidity, truffle

Look at this basic Solidity contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.6.11;

contract MyContract {
   string[] public tmp;
   ...

   function read_tmp() public view returns(string[] memory){
      return tmp;
   }
}
```

I have create a scaffolded truffle react project.

First, i get an error when trying to deploy this contract with this command:

```
truffle migrate --network ropsten --reset
```

The error is:

> TypeError: This type is only supported in ABIEncoderV2. Use "pragma
> experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the feature.

This error is due to string[] return type of read_tmp.
I am not happy do to that but i have add this line at the top of my contract and the deploy works now:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

My first question is: Why should i enable experimental features ? My 0.6.11 compiler version should allow this feature natively...

My second question is i have tried this in App.js file:

```
await this.state.contract.methods.tmp().call();
```

Solidity should create automatically a getter called tmp() for tmp public field.

I do not understand why but i have this javascript error in my browser:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of parameters for "tmp".
> Got 0 expected 1!

Everything works if i call read_tmp(). So my question is why tmp() needs an argument ? (i have tried to pass an integer but it does not work)

Thanks a lot

Comment: `My 0.6.11 compiler version should allow this feature natively...` - no, it shouldn't (what makes you think it should?).

Comment: I have seen some projects on github which works with the same pragma compiler version and return string arrays...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve whole array from solidity. You have to choose the index, that is why it is expecting 1 argument. If you want to get whole array elements in javascript, in solidity define a function to get the length of the array.

```
//Contract Code

function getTmpCount() public view returns(uint){
    return tmp.length;
}
```

then in javascript code:

```
// you get the lenght of the array
const tmpCount = await contract.methods.getTmpCount().call()

const tmps = await Promise.all(
    Array(tmpCount)
      .fill()  
      .map((element, index) => {
        return campaign.methods.tmp(index).call();
      })
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

For `type[] public arr`, the compiler auto-generates the following function:

```
function arr(uint256 index) public view returns (type) {
    return arr[index];
}
```

It is not added to the source code of course, because that would yield a naming collision.

But it is added to the byte-code itself, essentially becoming a part of the contract.

If you want a function which returns the entire array, then you need to implement it yourself:

```
function getArr() public view returns (type[] memory) {
    return arr;
}
```

---

With regards to:

> My 0.6.11 compiler version should allow this feature natively...

That's wrong; this feature is support under ABI encoder V2, which is activated by default only starting from solc 0.8.0 (as stated in the [Solidity 0.8.0 Release Announcement](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/12/16/solidity-v0.8.0-release-announcement/)).